# Java ArrayList<Double> IndexOutOfBoundsException Problem

Tags: java, collections

I've got a Problem with `ArrayList`. I need it to store a result. Because I want to start with element n I tried to give the `ArrayList` a capacity with `ensureCapacity(n+1)` to use `set(n,x)` but I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I tried to store n `add(x)` before the use of set and this works.

So I'd like to know why it doesn't work on my way and how to solve this because put n times a `add(x)` isn't a good style ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't like using your own loop and the list `add` method directly then there is another way. Create your `ArrayList` with the number of elements you want it directly like this:

```
final int MAX_ELEMENTS = 1000;
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(
    Collections.<Integer>nCopies(MAX_ELEMENTS, null));
```

Or, if you already have a list that you want to expand the size by `n` elements:

```
myList.addAll(Collections.<Integer>nCopies(n, null));
```

(Note, I assumed here that the list would be holding `Integer` objects, but you can change this to your custom type. If you are working with raw/pre-Java 5 types then just drop the generic declarations.)

As for your actual question: capacity != contents. An ArrayList internally has both a physical array and a count of what is actually in it. Increasing the capacity, changes the internal array so it can hold that many elements, however, the count does not change. You need to add elements to increase that count.

On the other hand, if you are just trying to set specific elements and know the maximum that you want to use, why not use an array directly? If you then need to pass this array to an API that takes `List`s, then use `Arrays.asList`. The other classes could still change contents of your backing array but it would not be able to increase the size or capacity of it.

Answer (score 7):

When you change the capacity of an ArrayList it doesn't create any elements, it just reserves memory where there could be elements. You can check the size before and after adjusting the capacity and you will see that it does not change.

The purpose of changing the capacity is if you know in advance how many elements you will have, then you can avoid unnecessary repeated resizing as you add new elements, and you can avoid memory wastage from excess unused capacity.

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, `ensureCapacity()` is just related to performance, is not frequently used by the common user.

From Bruce Eckel's *Thinking in Java* book:

> In a private message, Joshua Bloch
>   wrote: "... I believe that we erred by
>   allowing implementation details (such
>   as hash table size and load factor)
>   into our APIs. The client should
>   perhaps tell us the maximum expected
>   size of a collection, and we should
>   take it from there. Clients can easily
>   do more harm than good by choosing
>   values for these parameters. As an
>   extreme example, consider Vector's
>   capacityIncrement. No one should ever
>   set this, and we shouldn't have
>   provided it. If you set it to any
>   non-zero value, the asymptotic cost of
>   a sequence of appends goes from linear
>   to quadratic. In other words, it
>   destroys your performance. Over time,
>   we're beginning to wise up about this
>   sort of thing. If you look at
>   IdentityHashMap, you'll see that it
>   has no low-level tuning parameters"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because *ensureCapacity()* only makes sure that there is enough memory allocated for adding objects to an ArrayList, I believe this is in case you want to add multiple objects at once, without having to relocate memory.

To do what you want you would have to initiate the ArrayList with null elements first...

```
int n = 10;  //capacity required
ArrayList foo = new ArrayList();

for( int i=0; i<=n; i++ ) {
      foo.add(null);
}
```

Then you have objects in the List that you can reference via index and you wont receive the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`ensureCapacity()` has another purpose. It should be used in cases when you get to know the required size of the `List` after it has been constructed. If you know the size before it is constructor, just pass it as a an argument to the constructor.

In the former case use `ensureCapacity()` to save multiple copying of the backing array on each addition. However, using that method leaves the structure in a seemingly inconsistent state

- the size of the backing array is increased
- the `size` field on the `ArrayList` isn't.

This, however, is normal, since *the capacity != size*

Use the `add(..)` method, which is the only one that is increasing the `size` field:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.ensureCapacity(5); // this can be done with constructing new ArrayList(5)

for (int i = 0; i < list.size - 1; i ++) {
   list.add(null);
}
list.add(yourObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should rethink the choice of using `List<Double>`.  It might be that a `Map<Integer,Double>` would be more appropriate if elements are to be added in an odd order.

Whether this is appropriate depends on knowledge about your usage that I don't have at the moment though.

Is the data structure eventually going to be completely filled, or is the data sparse?

Comment: That would be the cleanest solution but the ArrayList is used as an argument in a method that only takes ArrayList. Maybe if I've got enough time I'll overload it for using Map insted.

Comment: You might also consider loading a Map and then writing a method to build an ArrayList from the contents of the map after it gets loaded.

But if you really need an ArrayList, the solution posted by Bozho might be just fine.

Comment: "the ArrayList is used as an argument in a method that only takes ArrayList" Seriously?  There is code out there that takes `ArrayList` rather than just `List`?

Comment: @R. Bemrose - Of course there is!  Not that there should be ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

what other people said about ensureCapacity() ...

you should write a class like DynamicArrayList extends ArrayList. then just overrride add(n,x) to do with for loop add(null) logic specified about.